# Complex Derivative conjugate of function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is  complex derivatiable in any point the function :
$f(z)=(x-iy)^{7}-7(x-iy)+(x+iy)^{2},\forall z\in\mathbb{C},z=x+iy$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Euler on this. To quote William Dunham, *Euler, The Master of Us All*: "Without apology or embarrassment, he treated these numbers as equal players upon the mathematical stage and showed how to take their roots, logs, sines, and cosines. In so doing, he gave to complex numbers his invaluable imprimatur."

I have never had a problem treating $i$ as anything but another constant in such problems. However, if you wish to take the derivative w.r.t $z$ you might try to express the function i.t.o. $z$.